Differences between two lists in python
I have two lists
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['a','e','f','b','g']

I want to return 3 lists
in_both = ['a','b']
only_in_list1 = ['c','d']
only_in_list2 = ['e','f','g']

Apologies for the simple question I have never used sets before.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets should explain it.

You'd do three different set operations to get these three different differences…

list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['a','e','f','b','g']

set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)

in_both = sorted(set1 & set2)
only_in_list1 = sorted(set1 - set2)
only_in_list2 = sorted(set2 - set1)


Note however, that it won't handle multiple occurences of items, e.g. for lists [1, 1, 2, 2, 3] and [1, 1, 2, 2] the in_both list will compute [1, 2], not  [1, 1, 2, 2]

Yes. For that case, I'd suggest only_in_list1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in set2] and only_in_list2 = [x for x in list2 if x not in set1].

In this instances the items in the list are unique but this is very helpful thank you!

You will convert your lists into sets and do set operations
intersection:

Returns the intersection of two sets as a new set.

difference:

Returns the difference of two or more sets as a new set.

list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['a','e','f','b','g']

set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)

in_both = set1.intersection(set2)
only_in_list1 = set1.difference(set2)
only_in_list2 = set2.difference(set1)

Note:
You can use & operator instead of intersection and  - operator instead of difference method
eg.
in_both = set1 & set2
only_in_list1 = set1 - set2
only_in_list2 = set2 - set1


Not a better solution but something you can use instead of set
list2 = ['a', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'g']

in_both = [item for item in list1 if item in list2]
only_in_list1 = [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
only_in_list2 = [item for item in list2 if item not in list1]

print("in_both:", in_both)
print("only_in_list1:", only_in_list1)
print("only_in_list2:", only_in_list2)


I don't see any better way other than using set, since this is exactly a set intersection/difference problem. So I would suggest to first convert the lists to sets, take the intersections and differences between them, then convert the resulting sets back to list. Of course, element ordering will not be preserved.
